# Crear Botones en forma dinamica (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de ventas con c# y quiero hacer que en la ventana donde se escogen los productos para vender se pueda filtrar por categoría, pero que cada categoría sea un botón y que usuario pueda seleccionar ahí la categoría que desea, la cosa esta en que el usuario puede crear tantas categorías como el quiera y mi consulta es si se pueden crear botones de forma automática en base al numero de categorías.

Pd: Intento hacer algo como [Esto](https://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/69668000/69668538/scr_1380116856-700x437.png)

Comment: tal vez esto te ayude... https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/aa288409(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira esto...

```
      public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Button[,] boton = new Button[10, 10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                boton[i, j] = new Button();
                boton[i, j].Width = 40;
                boton[i, j].Height = 20;
                boton[i, j].Text = String.Format("{0},{1}", i, j);
                boton[i, j].Top = i * 20;
                boton[i, j].Left = j * 40;
                this.Controls.Add(boton[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola, pues si me ayuda a crear los botones en función del numero de categorías pero no veo como hacer que el texto de cada botón corresponda a una categoria.

Comment: @Andres Cabrera  tienes una lista de categorías?

Comment: La lista la obtengo de la base de datos mediante un select.

Comment: en el primer for haz un recorrido al tamaño de tu lista, en el segunto al numero de botones por fila y en esta linea pones el nombre(suponineto que tienes una lista de categorias)... boton[i, j].Text = String.Format("{0}", listaCategorias.getCategoria());